# knitting as rpptx_document does not recognize my ppt template (Officedown)

Tags: r, r-markdown, officedown

I'm trying to create a powerpoint document with officedown using a template:

````
---
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author: "Your Name"
title: "Officedown test"
output: 
  officedown::rpptx_document:
  reference_doc: template.pptx
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, fig.cap = TRUE)
library(officedown)
library(officer)
library(dplyr)
```

## Table

```{r, echo = FALSE}
ppt_template <- read_pptx("template.pptx")
layout_summary(ppt_template) %>%  knitr::kable()
```
````

As a result, I get a powerpoint presentation that doesn't use the template provided. I don't seem to get any warning/error message:

```
processing file: testing_officedown.Rmd
  |..............                                                        |  20%
   inline R code fragments

  |............................                                          |  40%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |..........................................                            |  60%
  ordinary text without R code

  |........................................................              |  80%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ echo: logi FALSE

  |......................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


"C:/.../RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS testing_officedown.knit.md --to pptx --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output testing_officedown.pptx --reference-doc "C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYZ89AI\filed7423372e06.pptx" 
output file: testing_officedown.knit.md


Output created: testing_officedown.pptx
```

Please note that:

- I have no issues using the template with rmarkdown powerpoint_presentation.
- I've tried this without success: [Use PowerPoint template with officedown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67692499/use-powerpoint-template-with-officedown) and this one https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown/issues/65

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: reference_doc is an argument of rpptx_document, not an argument of output

Comment: Thanks, @DavidGohel I'm kind of ashamed that I didn't notice such a simple mistake.

Comment: Don't worry, it happens, and you should be proud for having provided a clear *reprex* that help users  to help you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David said, reference_doc is an argument of rpptx_document:

```
---
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author: "Your Name"
title: "Officedown test"
output: 
  officedown::rpptx_document: 
    reference_doc: template.pptx
---
```